# Trying to post data from react.js to node.js but doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to post data from react.js (front-end) to node.js (back-end with the mysql config), basically a user inputs a value in the search bar, then when he presses enter, it would send the value written in text box to node.js. When I am entering an input pressing enter from react.js front end user interface, it should display in the terminal of my node.js file, however nothing shows.

**REACT.JS CONTENT**

```
keyPress = (e) => {
if(e.keyCode == 13){

  this.setState({
      WorkInProgressSearchTerm: e.target.value
  })

  fetch(
    'http://localhost:3000/search',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.WorkInProgressSearchTerm),
    },
  ) // send POST request


  window.location.reload();
 }
}
```

**NODE.JS CONTENT**

```
app.post('http://localhost:3000/search', function(req, res) {
var data = req.body;
console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: In your node.js app, I assume you are using Express, I think you have to only specify the route in `app.post` like `app.post('/search', req => console.log(req.body));`

Comment: I changed it and yeah i am using express, but it didn't do anything also i get this error on my console log:                         
**POST http://localhost:3000/search 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: First, check your node app is running at `http://localhost:3000` then modify the route like so : `app.post('/search', /* your function */)`. It should solve your problem

Comment: @3Dos He wouldn't be getting 404's if the server wasn't running. This is definitely related to a routing issue. Ensure the route is setup correctly.

Comment: got it work to work and implemented my search function with the sql database thanks :D